# App crashes while adding a UITextField on UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app with Swift 5, that have two viewControllers. The first one, has a button that presents the second viewController. Code of the 2º viewController:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import Firebase
import Hero

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class RegistroViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    //MARK: ATRIBUTOS
    var db: Firestore!

    // Instancias recursos
    let gradientBackground = GradientView()
    let vista = RegistroView()

    //MARK: viewDidLoad()
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Mostrar fondo gradiente
        gradientBackground.mostrarGradientBackground(viewController: self)

        // Instanciar Firestore
        db = Firestore.firestore()

        // Configuracion navigationBar
        navBarSettings()

        // Mostrar objetos de la vista
        vista.mostrarVista(viewController: self)
    }

    // Funcion para configuracion de navigationBar
    func navBarSettings() {

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationItem.title = "Registro"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancelar", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelarRegistro))

    }

    @objc public func cancelarRegistro(sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
        self.hero.modalAnimationType = .cover(direction: .down)
        self.hero.dismissViewController()
    }

}
```

Code of RegistroView:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class RegistroView: UIView {

    // Color
    let customAzul = UIColor(red: 137/255, green: 177/255, blue: 223/255, alpha: 1)

    //scrollView y stackView
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()

    // Objetos para stackView
    let datosPersonales = UILabel()
    let nombreTextField = UITextField()
    let apellidoTextField = UITextField()

    func mostrarVista(viewController: UIViewController){

        // Instanciar viewController recibido
        let vc = viewController

        // Agrego scrollView a la vista del viewController
        vc.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // Configuracion scrollView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: vc.view.frame.width, height: vc.view.frame.height * 2)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        // Agrego stackView al scrollView
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        // Configuracion stackView
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.width.equalToSuperview() // Ancho igual al scrollView
            maker.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10) // Posicion Y de arriba: 10px más abajo
            maker.bottom.equalToSuperview() // Posicion Y de abajo: igual a scrollView
            maker.centerX.equalToSuperview() // stackView centrado horizontalmente
        }

        // Fuente para labels
        let fuente = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)

        // leftView para textFields
        let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10.0, height: 2.0))

        // Configuracion datosPersonales
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(datosPersonales)

        datosPersonales.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        datosPersonales.text = "Datos Personales"
        datosPersonales.textColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 135/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
        datosPersonales.font = fuente

        // Configuracion nombreTextField
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(nombreTextField)

        nombreTextField.text = ""
        nombreTextField.placeholder = "Nombre"
        nombreTextField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        nombreTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        nombreTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        nombreTextField.layer.borderWidth = 4
        nombreTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 135/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        nombreTextField.leftView = leftView
        nombreTextField.leftViewMode = .always
        nombreTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8)
            maker.height.equalTo(45)
        }

        // Configuracion apellidoTextField
        /*stackView.addArrangedSubview(apellidoTextField)

        apellidoTextField.text = ""
        apellidoTextField.placeholder = "Apellido"
        apellidoTextField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        apellidoTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        apellidoTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        apellidoTextField.layer.borderWidth = 4
        apellidoTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 135/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        apellidoTextField.leftView = leftView
        apellidoTextField.leftViewMode = .always
        apellidoTextField.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8)
            maker.height.equalTo(45)
        }*/
    }

}
```

The 2º viewController has a UIScrollView as a suubview, and the scrollView has inside an verticalStackView. When stackView contains the first label (datosPersonales) and the first textField (nombreTextField), the app runs perfectly; but, at the moment of adding a second textField (declared as apellidoTextField) to the stackView and runs the app again, when i touch the button in the 1º viewController, the app freezes, I can't do anything else and Xcode don't show me any error or end execution.

How can I solve this problem?

I'm **NOT** using Storyboards

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be an issue that you are using the same left view for both text fields.

Comment: Thank you! I created another leftView and it works perfect!

Comment: I'll make it an answer that other people with the same problem see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `leftView`. Use another `leftView` for the second text field.